Matrix of $T,T'$ and description of $T'$ in terms of the dual basis.
Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:
Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Suppose that $(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(w_1, w_2, w_3)$ is a basis of $W.$
Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ by requiring $T(v_1) = w_1, T(v_2) = w_2, T(v_3) = 0, T(v_4) = 0.$
I want to answer the following questions:
$(a)$ Write the matrix of $T$ with respect to the given basis for $V$ and $W.$
Here is my answer to this question:
$$(1 \quad  1 \quad 0 \quad 0)$$
Am I correct or I am missing something?
$(b)$ Use the notation $\phi_i$ for the elements of the dual basis of $V'$ and the notation $\theta_j$ for elements of the dual basis of $W'.$ What equation defines the dual basis of $V'$?
Here is my answer to this question:
$$
\phi_i(v_j) =\begin{cases}
   1, & \text{if $i=j$}\\
            0, & \text{if $i \neq j.$}
   \end{cases}
$$
$(c)$ Give a description of $T'$ in terms of the dual basis of part $(b),$ this one I do not know how to solve, can anyone clarify this to me ,please?
$(d)$ Give the matrix of $T'$ with respect to the dual bases of part $(b).$this one I also do not know how to solve, can anyone clarify this to me ,please?

For part $(a)$, the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ should tell you that your answer is incorrect. The basis of $V$ is a list of length $4$, and the basis of $W$ is a list of length $3$. Then you should expect the matrix of $T$ to have $4$ columns and $3$ rows. Can you show your work for part $(a)$?

So the answer to (a) is the matrix \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} @PaulAsh

@PaulAsh what about the answer to my remaining questions.

sorry the last row should not be there. @PaulAsh

a) You should have a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 4}$ as an answer to this question. The first column should tell you where the first basis vector of $V$ maps to, the second tells you where the second basis vector of $V$ maps to etc. In short, you are missing something.
b) As far as I can tell, this is correct. It is strange to call the dual vectors in both $V'$ and $W'$, $\phi$. You should perhaps have $\phi_i \in V'$ and $\psi_i \in W'$.
c) It should be the case that $\psi(Tv) = (T'\psi)(v)$ for all vectors $v \in V.$ Because $Tv_1 = w_1,$ $Tv_2 = w_2,$ and $Tv_i = 0$ for $i=3,4$  it should be pretty easy to describe the action of $T'$ on $W'$.
d) After working everything out by hand you should end up seeing the relationship that $\mathrm{mat}(T') = T^\ast$.

i edited the question in part(b), sorry about that

I did not get what do you mean by $T^*$

By $T^*$ he means the transpose of the matrix of $T$.

So the answer to (a) is the matrix \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}

for (c) and (d) can you provide the answer please, I posted the question because they were not easy for me.

for part (c), where does your $\psi$ lies?

sorry the last row should not be there

First, for part (d), Paul is right, I mean the transpose of $T$. Your matrix is correct, sans the last row, like you noted.

For part (c) we should for each $j=1, 2, 3$ we should test $T'\psi_j = a\phi_1 + b\phi_2 + c\phi_3 + d\phi_4$ against the basis vectors of $V$ to see what we should set $a, b, c, d$ to. For example
$$(T'\psi_1)(v_1) = \psi_1(Tv_1) = \psi_1(w_1) = 1$$
$$(T'\psi_1)(v_2) = \psi_1(Tv_2) = \psi_1(w_2) = 0$$
$$(T'\psi_1)(v_i) = \psi_1(Tv_i) = \psi_1(0) = 0$$
for $i=3, 4$. So $T'\psi_1 = \phi_1$. If we repeat for $j=2, 3$ we get a complete description of the action of $T'$ on $W'$.

So that you can check your work, the action of $T'$ on the other basis vectors of $W'$ is $T'\psi_2 = \phi_2$ and $T'\psi_3 = 0$.
